# Best way to do numbering in LaTeX

Tags: numbering

I have use enumerator before, that is good when it comes to numbering with letters after your initial number such as 2a, 2b etc. But now I have problem where I want to number my questions 2.1.1, 2.1.2. I tried to use the enumerator

```
\textbf{Question 2.1}\\
\HRule
\begin{enumerate}[(2.1.1)]\itemsep1pt

\end{enumerate}
```

But this gives me error, what would it the best way to handle this situation.

Comment: Could you provide a complete MWE? Is 'Question' some kind of environment? In general, you should *never* hard code enumerations in `LaTeX`, and let it handle them using `counter`s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with the list environment fairly easily

Below is lifted from http://www.maa.org/latex/ltx-260.html

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\begin{document} 

\newcounter{Lcount}

\begin{list}{2.1.\arabic{Lcount}}{\usecounter{Lcount}\setlength{\rightmargin}{\leftmargin}}
\item $f(x)=x^2$ Find $f'(x)$
\item What is an antiderivative of $f(x)=x^2$
\end{list}
\end{document}
```

I do however agree it is bad form to hard code numbering of questions. But if you're just making your own exams I could see why you might do this.

Comment: This answer cannot be correct. Either it is not what OP asks for, or this is a solution that is systematically mis-conceptual and _should never be advised._